# How to getback to AR after VR scene get finished in unity(using vuforia)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, virtual-reality

I am working on Unity + Vuforia for AR/VR scene where my VR scene is called by a trigger and after the scene I want to get back to AR.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GameManager instance;

    public GameObject[] planes;

    public TransitionManager mTransitionManager;

    public VideoPlayer[] vps;

    public void Awake(){
        instance = this;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        vps = new VideoPlayer[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            vps [i] = planes [i].GetComponent<VideoPlayer> ();

            ARPort.SetActive (false);
        }

        StartCoroutine (StartSequence ());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator StartSequence(){
        //Wait for video [0] to finish

        yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)vps[0].clip.length);
        Destroy (planes [0]);

        planes [1].SetActive (true);

        //Wait for video [1] to finish
        yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)vps[1].clip.length);
        Destroy (planes [1]);
        planes [2].SetActive (true);

        //Wait for video [2] to finish
        yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)vps[2].clip.length);
        Destroy (planes [2]);
        planes [3].SetActive (true);

        //Wait for video [3] to finish
        yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)vps[3].clip.length);
        Destroy (planes [3]);

        //Now start AR part again

        MixedRealityController.Instance.SetMode (MixedRealityController.Mode.HANDHELD_AR);
    }
```

This code starts camera for few milliseconds and after that it turns on the VR scene again. How can I solve this error??

[Check the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpLhk.png)